# In Highcharter is it possible to renormalize the data and replot it every time the navigator changes the plot area?

Tags: javascript, r, events, highcharts, r-highcharter

My goal, using highcharter, is to plot multiple total return time series of different financial assets, where the first y-axis value for all series is 1 (or 100%). Then, when the navigator changes the visible range of the x-axis, I'd like to renormalize all the series so that they again start from 1 in the new x-axis range (so that we can compare performance over any timespan).

I was able to modify an existing fiddle to do something similar for a small array of data points: https://jsfiddle.net/jgcdh46e/12/

But I can't get the following (toy example) R highcharter code to work. It runs and it plots the series, but when I move the navigator bar to change the x-axis range, it doesn't renormalize the data.

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)

#Use SPY as an example asset
SPY <- getSymbols('SPY', src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)$SPY.Adjusted
SPY <- SPY / as.numeric(SPY[1]) #Normalize the data to start at 1

hc <- highchart(type = 'stock')
hc <- hc_chart(hc, events = list(
  selection = JS("function(event) {
    if (event.xAxis) {
        let min = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].min, 2),
            max = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].max, 2)
          
          // Get the y value of the first x value in the zoomed-in plot area
          let firstX = event.xAxis[0].min;
          let series = this.series[0];
          let firstY = null;
          for (let i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++) {
            if (series.data[i].x >= firstX) {
              firstY = series.data[i].y;
              break;
            }
          }

          // Normalize data by dividing all values by the first y value
          for (let i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++) {
            series.data[i].update(series.data[i].y / firstY);
          }
        } else { 
          
          // Restore original data when zoomed out to full range
          let series = this.series[0];
          for (let i = 0; i < series.options.data.length; i++) {
            series.data[i].update(series.options.data[i]);
          }
        }
    }")
)
)
hc <- hc_add_series(hc, SPY, type = "line", name = "SPY")
hc
```

I would be grateful for any insight into what might be going wrong and exceptionally grateful if anyone were able to generalize the code to more than one asset.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using the plotOptions.series.compare and related options in HighCharts.

Following up on the example above:

```
library(quantmod)
library(highcharter)

SPY <- getSymbols('SPY', src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)$SPY.Adjusted
QQQ <- getSymbols('QQQ', src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)$QQQ.Adjusted

mat <- na.omit(cbind(SPY, QQQ))
spy <- mat[,1]/as.numeric(mat[1,1])
qqq <- mat[,2]/as.numeric(mat[1,2])

hc <- highchart(type = 'stock')
hc <- hc_add_series(hc, spy, type = "line", name = "SPY")
hc <- hc_add_series(hc, qqq, type = "line", name = "QQQ")
hc <- hc_plotOptions(hc, series = list(compareStart = TRUE, compare = 'percent', compareBase = 100))
hc
```